# how to call a method with multiple input parameters in another method

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parameters

I am creating a game and I'm stuck on creating a successful physics contact method.

```
func bulletCollisionWithEnemy1(enemy1: SKSpriteNode, bullet1: SKSpriteNode){ // my enemy1 and bullet are defined in my game scene 

    score += 1
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    bullet1.removeFromParent ()
    hitCount++ 
}

func enemy1Hit (enemy1:Enemy1) { //my enemy1 is defined in my game scene and my Enemy1 is a separate SKSNode class i have created containing physics properties and vars ect. 

    if (enemy1.hit() == true) {
        //enemy hit animation
    }else{
       //for animations
    }
}
```

here is where i define the contact physics

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet1) && 
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy1) ||
        (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy1) && 
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet1)) {

        if let firstNode = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode, secondNode = secondBody .node as? SKSpriteNode {

            bulletCollisionWithEnemy1((firstNode), bullet1:  (secondNode))
        }
```

where my problem is i can't find a away to call my enemy1hit() function. My hit() function is defined in my Enemy1 class so i have to call my Enemy1 in the parameters aswell as call my hit class in my collision with bullet class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the assumption that class `Enemy1` is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` I think what you want is:

```
class Enemy1: SKSpriteNode {

    func bulletCollision(bullet1: SKSpriteNode){ // my enemy1 and bullet are defined in my game scene 
        score += 1
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        bullet1.removeFromParent ()
        hitCount++ 
    }

    func hit() { //my enemy1 is defined in my game 
        // scene and my Enemy1 is a separate SKSNode class i have created 
        //containing physics properties and vars ect. 

        if (enemy1.hit() == true) {
            //enemy hit animation
        } else {
           //for animations
        }
    }

}
```

Wherever your delegate is:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet1) && 
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy1) ||
        (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy1) && 
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet1)) {

        if let firstNode = firstBody.node as? Enemy1, secondNode = secondBody .node as? SKSpriteNode {
            firstNode.bulletCollision(secondNode)
            firstNode.hit()
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that the `bulletCollision` and `hit` methods are members of the `Enemy1` object and so can be called on the object rather than having to pass the object to them.

Comment: you do not have to call the secondNode in didBeginContact? @george Green?

Comment: and i have my score and score latel defined in my gameScene.swift file, so you want me to define my score in my enemy1 class? That would kind of be a pain and might cause problems later with saving scores or points

Comment: @gkolman No the score if fine globally since it is not specific to an entity. However being hit is specific to an enemy. I'm not sure what you mean by your 1st question here? Perhaps you could link me to the full class definition so I can better see what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: how am i supposed to call my hit () function in my contact method when my contact method is in my gameScene class and my hit () function is defined in my Enemy1Class @George Green

Comment: @gkolman I assume `didBeginContact` is in your gameScene class, so you can call the `hit` method because you have a reference to an instance of an `Enemy1` so can call the member function of that object. How familiar are you with object oriented programming? Might be worth getting a book on the basic concepts?